# How do I get the correct URL of an image field?

Tags: 7, entities, media

I'm trying to print out the URL of an image field using the following code.

```
<img src="<?php echo $field_company_logo['und'][0]['uri']; ?>" alt="<?php echo $company[0]['#markup']; ?>" />
```

The code gives me a URI like public://company-logos/image.png when I would need sites/default/files/company-logos/image.png.

What code should I use to print the image path (i.e. sites/default/files/company-logos/image.png)?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You want to use the [drupal_realpath()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!file.inc/function/drupal_realpath/7) function to convert the URI into the actual filesystem path.

```
echo drupal_realpath($field_company_logo['und'][0]['uri']);
```

You could also use [file_create_url()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!file.inc/function/file_create_url/7) to get the actual URL to the image, as opposed to a local filepath.

And the correct way to render an image is to run it through `theme_image()`:

```
echo theme('image', array(
  'path' => file_create_url($field_company_logo['und'][0]['uri']),
  'alt' => check_plain($company[0]['#markup']),
));
```

Also, accessing field data the way you're doing it isn't the preferred method. Have a look at [field_get_items()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!field!field.module/function/field_get_items/7) and the detailed example in the [Rendering Drupal Fields (the right way)](http://www.computerminds.co.uk/articles/rendering-drupal-7-fields-right-way) blog entry.

Comment: +1 for using the theme function, although I don't think you would actually want drupal_realpath() anymore. The theme function will automatically transform the URI.

Comment: file_create_url worked for me, thanks! realpath gave me the absolute url though which wouldn't render.

Comment: You can pass the stream path directly (public://...) and it will automatically generate the right path.

Answer (score 11):

If you literally just want to transform a URI into an actual URL, then you want the [file_create_url()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!file.inc/function/file_create_url/7) function, which is used like this:

```
$url = file_create_url($uri);
```

But you might find it easier to use a theme function, like Yuriy Babenko suggests:

```
$image_vars = array(
  'path' => $field_company_logo['und'][0]['uri'],
  'alt' => $company[0]['#markup'],
);
echo theme('image', $image_vars);
```

You can easily adapt this to use [theme_image_style()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!image!image.module/function/theme_image_style/7) instead, if you want a sized derivative of your image.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [Image URL Formatter](https://www.drupal.org/project/image_url_formatter) module. It allows to change the field format in order to get only the URL:

[image: Drupal field settings]

Bonus: it works with Views as well:

[image]