# How would I be able to get the full URL from an image field?

Tags: 8

In a node template, how would I be able to get the URL from an image field?
Like if it were something like this:

> {{ content.field_image.URL }}

Or if there is a similar alternative perhaps?

Answer (score 0):

Have you seen the answer of this [question](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/94263/how-to-get-correct-url-path-of-image-field)?

Answer (score 0):

`{{ content.field_image[0]['#item'].target_id }}` would return the file entity id.

`{{ content.field_image[0]['#item'].getUploadLocation() }}` would return the file upload location uri (public://image-1)

It is better to use a preprocess function for this kind of logic and pass the result as a variable.

Comment: How would one do that? I've been trying to accomplish this but I keep getting an undefined variable error.

Answer (score 0):

Getting the URL in a way that is actually a URL is not so easy and I think can currently only be done in preprocess. You need something like this:

`enter code here`file_create_url($variables['node']->field_image->entity->getFileUrl())